# How can i style specific button with css modules?

Tags: reactjs, css-modules, react-css-modules

I am using css modules in react because i want to have css scoped to specific component.I have Person.js and App.js file. I want only the button in the Person.js to have background color of red.

So i do

**Person.js**

```
import styles from './person.module.css';


const Person = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <button className={styles.button}>Person compo button</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Person;
```

**person.module.css**

```
.button {
    background-color: red;
}
```

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import Person from './Person';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <button className="button">App compo button</button>
     <Person></Person>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and now only the - Person compo button is with background color red. But i am using css class here.
What if i want to style the button in the Person.js file without using the class

so i will have in person.module.css only button styling

```
button {
   background-color: red;
}
```

how can i make now the button in my Person.js file to take this style from the person.module.css ?

Comment: I think there are multiple ways you could approach it. You could have a base 
button class and another specific class to use on the buttons in your `Person` component. Or you could make your styles objects, pass them around, override style properties, etc...

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to attach a class to the Person div:

```
const Person = () => {
    return (
        <div className={styles.person}>
            <button>Person compo button</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

And in your person.module.css, reference all the buttons inside the `.person` class:

```
.person button {
   background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Is there any other way, with which i could make this without using classes ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with any other way